# Can't catch the error from BehaviorSubject, or any subject in rxjs 7

Tags: rxjs, rxjs7

The idea is to catch the error message `Next err =================>` thrown after 6 sec. In console log we can see only first thrown error, which is werry strange behavior.
Here is link in stakblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tdpwu3?file=index.ts

```
import {
  interval,
  of,
  throwError,
  timer,
  ReplaySubject,
  Subject,
  BehaviorSubject,
} from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, retry, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit value every 1s
let source = new Subject();

const example = source.pipe(
  tap((ob) => console.log('OBJ: ', ob)),
  //retry 2 times on error
  retry({
    delay: (errors) => {
      console.log('Last error : ', errors);
      return timer(3000);
    },
  })
);

setTimeout(() => {
  source.error({ message: 'Error here !!!' });
}, 3000);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Next err =================>');
  //source = new BehaviorSubject({ status: 'open' });
  source.error({ message: 'Next err =================>' });
}, 6000);

const subscribe = example.subscribe();

source.next({ status: 'open' });
```

Comment: Your Stackblitz and the code shown here are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see strange behavior here. The source observable is **closed** once it emits the first error `{ message: 'Error here !!!' }`.

From the [docs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable#executing-observables):

> If either an Error or Complete notification is delivered, then nothing else can be delivered afterwards.

The second error `{ message: 'Next err =================>' }` is never emitted to the observable. So the second error is never seen inside the `retry`.